# What is the Index range of an Excel data sheets... How to use index range in Java?

Tags: java

I wants to know the index range of the sheets in an Excel file...

```
Line1:  String file = new String ("D:\\a.xls");
Line2:  HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Line3:  wb.getSheetName(0);
```

**At Line 3, i got the below error:**

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.validateSheetIndex(HSSFWorkbook.java:409)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getSheetName(HSSFWorkbook.java:541)
    at Excel.read(Excel.java:75)
    at Excel.main(Excel.java:63)

Comment: I have fixed this error with the below code:

Comment: String file = new String ("D:\\a.xls");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
String sn = wb.getSheetName(q);

Comment: Add this as an actual answer and mark correct, not a comment. People will then know not to continue help.

Answer (score 2):

I know the excel-indexes from VBA. It is 1-based. Try to change your code to

```
String file = new String ("D:\\a.xls");
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
wb.getSheetName(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just me on a whim, but I assume that excel sheet indexing isn't 0 based (like you are used to from c like languages) but probably is 1 based, i.e. x elements aren't indexed as `0..x-1` but rather `1..x`

I don't have experience with excel like this though, but give it a try and it might just be it